# Run powershell script at startup in visual studio

Tags: powershell, nuget, visual-studio-2013

I have a powershell file (script.ps1) that is in some of my visual studio solutions. The script contains utility functions for the project. 
At the moment, I just open the nugget package manager and copy and paste the content of the script and it runs fine. I can run the functions correctly from the nugget package manager. But this has to be done, each time I open the solution.

Is there a way to get this handle automatically each time I open the solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than copy pasting the entire thing, you can dot source the file

`. ".\script.ps1"`

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm.